# Order by * where *

Tags: mysql

Sorry that my english isn't the best.

Is it possible to do a "where" in "order by".

Example :

```
ORDER BY 
SUM(points), 
SUM(points) WHERE type = 1, 
SUM(goal), 
SUM(goal) WHERE type = 1
```

So as first we sort by points.

If anyone has the same number of `SUM(points)`, then we sort by `SUM(points) where type = 1`.

If anyone has the same number of `SUM(points)` and the same number of `SUM(points) where type = 1`, then we sort after `SUM(goal)`.

If anyone has the same in all 3, then it have to sort by `SUM(goal) where type = 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN type=1 THEN points ELSE 0 END)
```

etc.

you should of course add `DESC` on all order conditions, if you want the "best" first ;)

And the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1957f/2)

Comment: Cool, just what i was looking for.

But what if i will order by (SUM(goal)-SUM(goala)) where type=1??

Comment: @DonWagner well, if condition apply to both, it should just be `SUM(case WHEN type=1 then goal - goala else 0 end)` cause `SUM(a) - SUM(b) == SUM( a-b)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY
  SUM(points),
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN points ELSE 0 END),
  SUM(goal),
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN goal ELSE 0 END)
```